# Custom master page breaks "Change the look"

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage

- In **Design Manager: Edit Master Pages** click on "Create a minimal master page" and ensure the new master page is published:

[image: Create minimal master page]
[image: Publish master page]

---

- In **Site Master Page Settings** set this new master page as the default for pages and system pages:

[image: Set master page]

---

- In **Change the look** choose any of the default looks e.g. Orange:

[image: Change the look]

---

- The subsequent **designbuilder.aspx** page hangs with no preview (with the message "Working on it..." in the top-right):

[image: designbuilder.aspx hangs]

---

- Click **Try it out** presents a correlation ID error:

[image: Correlation ID error]

---

Can someone help with the missing step?

Comment: Have you searched log against this correlation ID? What's the error against it?

Comment: Have tried the same steps on o365 SharePoint but could not get any error. As Ganesh said, you need to check the correlation id in the logs for the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Theme** wasn't properly configured.

In particular, the fact that the ".preview" file was not properly configured was the reason that the **designbuilder.aspx** page was breaking.

The below Microsoft articles need to read to understand how all the relevant theme files interact:

- [Themes Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/themes-overview-for-sharepoint)
- [How To Create A Master Page Preview File In SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-master-page-preview-file-in-sharepoint)
- [How To Deploy A Custom Theme In SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint)
- [How To Make Custom CSS Files Themable In SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-make-custom-css-files-themable-in-sharepoint)
- [Upgrade Custom Themes And CSS To SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/upgrade-custom-themes-and-css-to-sharepoint)
- [Color Palettes And Fonts In SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/color-palettes-and-fonts-in-sharepoint)

The below components need to be considered for a successful theme:
 - Color Palette
 - Font Scheme
 - Master Page
 - Master Page Preview
 - Composed Look
 - Change the Look
 - Design Gallery